# How to create a multi-dimensional barchart

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to create a bar chart with lattice, which has two groupings. The first grouping is stacked, whereas the second is not. For example:

```
a <- factor(rep(c(1,2), times = 6))
b <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3), times = 4))
c <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), times = 3))
d <- factor(rep(c("true", "false"), each = 6))
e <- factor(rep(c("yes", "no", "may be"), each = 4))
value <- c(5,8,2,4,1,8,9,3,5,6,3,12)
```

At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
a <- factor(rep(c(1,2), times = 6))
b <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3), times = 4))
c <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), times = 3))
d <- factor(rep(c("true", "false"), each = 6))
e <- factor(rep(c("yes", "no", "may be"), each = 4))
value <- c(5,8,2,4,1,8,9,3,5,6,3,12)

barchart(value ~ a | b + c, 
       groups = d, stack = FALSE, 
       auto.key=TRUE,
       scales = list(x = "free"))
```

This results in length(b)*length(c) set of barplots, each with length(a) sets of bars. Each set of bars has a bar for "true" and a bar for "false". What I would also like to add is the stacked value of e, such that each "true" bar will be divided into three sections: the bottom one will be for "yes", then "no" and them "may be" and the same with the "false" bar.

I realise that the graph will be quite complex, however it is the best way to represent the data which I have. Adding e in the formula, as in b + c + e is not an option, as I already have a set of plots and I need to keep to the same format, as they are related to each other. On the other hand having 6 bars in each set will make readability much harder.

Thanks!

Comment: This gives me a plot with only one value of d (i.e., either true or false, not both) per facet. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` will do the job relatively easily, if using `lattice` isn't a hard requirement for you. I took the liberty of expanding your data set so that all of the combinations of a, b, c, d, and e would be present.

```
# Load required packages
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)

# Make factors with the same levels as in the original post
#   but 100x longer, and in random order so all combinations are present
a <- sample(factor(rep(c(1,2), times = 600)))
b <- sample(factor(rep(c(1,2,3), times = 400)))
c <- sample(factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), times = 300)))
d <- sample(factor(rep(c("true", "false"), each = 600)))
e <- sample(factor(rep(c("yes", "no", "may be"), each = 400)))
value <- runif(1200)

# Put them in a data frame
df <- data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, value=value)

# Calculate the sum of the value columns for each unique combination of a, b, c, d, and e
#   I think this is what you'd like - am not totally sure
ds <- ddply(df, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), summarise, sum.value=sum(value, na.omit=TRUE))

# Make the plot
ggplot(ds, aes(x=d, y=sum.value, fill=e)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(a~b+c) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]

Comment: I had never used ggplot2 before, but this does look like what I need. Thank you so very much! :)

Comment: There's a bit of a learning curve to ggplot2, but it shouldn't be too bad if you're used to lattice, and I think it ultimately makes lots of tasks much easier.